# Namespace in C# when using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to teach myself AJAX/Web services using C# and javascript. And I think I'm having a namespace issue, judging by the Google-ing I've done.

First of all, my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SimpleAJAX
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetServerResponse(string callerName)
        {
            if (callerName == string.Empty)
                throw new Exception("Web Service Exception: invalid argument");

            return string.Format("Service responded to {0} at {1}", callerName, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

The Web Service.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Web Service call from client-side JavaScript</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function SendRequest() {
            MySampleService.GetServerResponse(form1.MyTextBox.value, OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
        }

        function OnComplete(arg)
        {
            alert(arg);
        }

        function OnTimeOut(arg)
        {
            alert("timeOut has occured");
        }

        function OnError(arg)
        {
            alert("error has occured: " + arg._message);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/MySampleService.asmx" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="" id="MyTextBox" />
            <input type="button" value="Send Request to the Web Service" id="RequestButton" 
                onclick="return SendRequest()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The aspx page.

Taken from (http://www.semenoff.dk/en/Code-Corner/ASP.Net.AJAX/WebService-From-JavaScript.aspx)

And when I run it I get a "'MySampleService' is undefined" error. I followed the tutorial exactly, but obviously I'm still doing something wrong. Little help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 function SendRequest() {
            SimpleAJAX.WebService1.GetServerResponse(form1.MyTextBox.value, OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to include your namespace and your service's actual class name in the call:

```
SimpleAJAX.WebService1.GetServerResponse(form1.MyTextBox.value, OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
```

To see the exact structure of the JavaScript proxy that ASP.NET generates for your ScriptReference, open `WebService1.asmx/jsdebug` in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any class called "MySampleService". Your class is named WebService1, so you should use

```
SimpleAJAX.WebService1.GetServerResponse(form1.MyTextBox.value, OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
```